# How to send EPL2 command to a Zebra LP2844 printer via USB using C#

Tags: c#, usb, zebra-printers, epl

I am required to print labels and bar codes on zebra label printer using C#. I have never used them before but read and tried to figure out a way to do that. And I have come across this code from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091, but it didn't work. From my trials I can see that I was able to send the data to the printer but it doesn't respond and print. I am using buttons to send the command to the printer just like in the kb article.

```
private void  ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Allow the user to select a printer.
    string s =  "B26,26,0,UA0,2,2,152,B,\"{0}\"";
    PrintDialog pd =  new PrintDialog();
    pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
    if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
    {
       // Send a printer-specific to the printer.
       RawPrintrHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName,s);
       MessageBox.Show("Data sent to printer.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following two blog posts written by [Nicholas Piasecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32187/nicholas-piasecki) are an invaluable resource for everybody trying to print to Zebra printers from .NET:

- [Sending Raw EPL2 Directly to a Zebra LP2844 via C#](http://web.archive.org/web/20140922053236/http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c)
- [Using the EPL2 GW command to send an image to a Zebra thermal printer](http://web.archive.org/web/20141109172303/http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2013/02/using-the-epl2-gw-command/)

*([his website](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog) seems to be dead right now, so the links are going to the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/))*

I've been working with Zebra printers and EPL for more than 10 years, about 6 of them with .NET.
When I started with Zebra/EPL and .NET, those two blog posts were all I needed to get it to work.

---

Concerning this:

> And I have come across this code from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091, but it didn't work. From my trials I can see that I was able to send the data to the printer but it doesn't respond and print.

There's a bug in the code in that article, the solution is explained at the bottom of the first blog post that I linked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how do you add the reference     Skiviez.UndiesClient.Domain ? I mean is it a dll or where do I get it?

Comment: or there is no use of adding it?

Comment: You don't need it. [Skiviez is the company where Nicholas works](http://web.archive.org/web/20140923221412/http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/about/), so all the `Skiviez.*` references are probable in there because he copied his code samples from his actual production code.

Comment: @Mahlye.Sol: If my answer was helpful to you, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you so much for these links @ChristianSpecht.